# jquery how to rebind click event after re-creating checkbox inputs

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has a jquery datatable, one of the columns is a checkbox.
On document.ready I bind those checkboxes (identified by the class) with a click event.

Now upon making modifications to the table data, I refresh the table by clearing it and re-populating the rows.

However now the checkboxes lose their click event.

I know I need to re-bind the click event but I cannot figure out where that code has to go.

This is the function where I re-populate the table

```
function RefreshBuyerAgentTable(tableId, urlData) {
        var selBuyerAgid = -1;
        var selBuyerAgname = '';
        var oTbl = $(tableId).dataTable();

        //var oSettings = oTbl.fnSettings();

        oTbl.fnClearTable(this);
        var sItems = JSON.parse(urlData);
        for (var i = 0; i < sItems.length; i++) {

            oTbl.fnAddData(["<input type='checkbox' id='chkBuyer_" + sItems[i].BuyerAgentId + "' class='buyeragentcheckboxes'/><img src='../../images/edit_24x24.png' style='cursor: pointer' onclick='EditBuyerAgent(" + sItems[i].BuyerAgentId + ")' />", sItems[i].BuyerAgentFullName, sItems[i].BuyerAgentCompanyName]);
            if (sItems[i].BuyerAgentIsSelected){
                selBuyerAgid = sItems[i].BuyerAgentId;
                selBuyerAgname   = sItems[i].BuyerAgentFullName;

            }
        }
```

This is event binding I use in my document.ready section

```
$("#tblAgentInformationBuyerAgents tbody tr td .buyeragentcheckboxes").click(function(e) {
```

Comment: Use the delegate version of `on` instead of click. e.g. `.on("click", "selector-goes-here", function(){...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler.

```
$("#tblAgentInformationBuyerAgents").on("click", "tbody tr td .buyeragentcheckboxes", function(e) {
```

This way the event handler is not removed when the DOM is updated. My above example assumes that `#tblAgentInformationBuyerAgents` is always present in the DOM.

Your issue was that the event handlers were "attached" to the DOM elements so when you remove the DOM elements, the event handler also goes away.